# How to identify the cause of slowness of an external hard disk?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have 2 Western Digital external hard drives, namely:

- 1 [WD Elements 2TB USB 3.0 Portable Hard Drive (WDBU6Y0020BBK-NESN)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DULWSXI)
- 1 [WD My Passport Ultra 2 TB Portable External USB 3.0 Hard Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00E055H5O)

I connect them to my laptop ([MSI G Series GE70 0ND-033US 17.3-Inch Laptop (Black/Red)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0082JFD1W)), which runs Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

The 2 Western Digital external hard drives are slow, and I don't understand why. I tried two different USB cables, and two different USB ports.  All USB cables and USB ports are USB 3. All disks use NTFS.

---

Below are some CrystalDiskMark benchmarks:

WD My Passport Ultra with USB cable 1 USB port 1  (both USB cable and USB port are USB 3):

[image]

WD Elements with USB cable 1 on USB port 1 (both USB cable and USB port are USB 3):

[image]

WD Elements with USB cable 2 USB port 1  (both USB cable and USB port are USB 3):

[image]

WD Elements with USB cable 2 USB port 2  (both USB cable and USB port are USB 3):

[image]

---

In theory, everything is USB 3: the EHD, the cable, and the computer's USB port. According to HD Tune Pro 5.50, both EHD are healthy.

What could explain the slowness of the external hard drives?

---

I benchmarked the [Seagate Backup Plus 4TB Portable External Hard Drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0196J40BA) using the same computer, cable and USB port. It gives much better results:

[image]

As a side note, it gives similar performances when formatted as exFAT:

[image]

The EHD also has more settings regarding the write-caching policy:

[image]

And its performances decrease as more content is added to the hard drive:

[image]

---

Answer to comments:

I installed [Intel's USB 3 drivers from the MSI website](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE70_0ND.html#down-driver):

[image]

BIOS settings:

[image]

Updating the Intel USB 3 drivers improved quite a bit:

[image]

Activating  WriteCache from the device manager (then rebooting) doesn't help:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could it be a driver issue - ie is it possible you have 2 different USB chipsets, or bios settings which are forcing port 1 to behave a USB2 rather then USB3?

Comment: Make sure you installed the XHCI driver from Intel (since you're using Windows 7), otherwise the host controller might fall back to EHCI mode.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks, is there a way to check whether the controller uses XHCI or EHCI? I did install the USB 3 driver, I updated the question to mention it.

Comment: @davidgo On the laptop, two USB ports are USB 2, and two USB ports are USB 3.

Comment: @davidgo I check the BIOS settings, they look ok to me, I added a screenshot in the question details.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to [latest version](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/21129/) of the driver

Comment: @TomYan Thanks, it did improve quite a bit: http://i.stack.imgur.com/leKa1.png However, still far from 90-130MB/s, where it is supposed to be from what I read ([example](http://superuser.com/a/607007/116475)).

Comment: activate the WriteCache for he drives in device manager

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks, good idea, I have just tried but it didn't help

Comment: Perhaps the Seagate drive supports UASP but not the two WD drives? *How* does the Seagate drive show in Device Manager?

Comment: Also, I just notice that the Seagate drive is basically empty while the two WD drives are close to being full. That's not really a fair test, especially to a spinning drive and if it is highly fragmented.

Comment: @TomYan Thanks, good point, I added more content on the Seagate and did the benchmark again: it does decrease the performances significantly but not as worse as WD. Maybe it is less fragmented indeed. How to check whether Seagate drive supports UASP?

Comment: Well the disk will show up as "SCSI disk" instead of "USB device" under disk drives in device manager. Also the controller will show up as a UAS controller under storage controller instead of USB mass storage under USB devices

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remember your disks are *mechanical* disks, which means any time you wanna get data from it, a small part has to move to where the data actually is and wait for the disk to spin enough time for the data to be read.

I have a USB3 2TB Toshiba external HDD, and I don't have more than 30MiB/s read & write speed either.

Oh, and as a word of advice, avoid WD hard drives. I had several of them that stopped working for no real reason, without any way to fix them (and one of them was a My Passport).

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't we expect a higher IO given that they are 5400 RPM? On my side, I've had ~8 WD, no failure so far, which is indeed quite surprising. I did have some Seagate and Lacie EHD failed. Everything is backed up in a local RAID 5 NAS + online when non sensitive. Also, I am surprised that one USB 3 port is twice slower than the other USB 3 port.

Comment: Standard speeds for HDDs are 5400RPM or 7200RPM. So your HDDs have actually the *lower* speed. Also, speed can slow down even more if you're trying to read or write many files spread everywhere on the disk's pysical surface. And sorry about ranting about disk failures ^^ but it's true only WD disks have failed me so far.

Comment: I added in the question a benchmark of a Seagate (5400 RPM), as you'll see read and write speed are 130 MB/s.